# Eclipse RCP Juno debugger doesn't stop at break points

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I am using Eclipse RPC Juno for modifying existing plugin projects. I have Java 1.7. When I run the application in debug mode, it doesn't stop at break points. I am certain that the code is executed. 
Does anyone have the same problem? How do you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You might have used the "Skip all breakpoints" command. That is the pressed button with the line from top left to bottom right in the screenshot below. If so, hit it again to enable all breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem under PyDev but couldn't figure it out because I thought it was PyDev-specific. This screenshot helped me immensely!